# Linked list — inserting a node at the end

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list

What is wrong in this code. During the insertion operation, when inserting the second element, the programs halts and Windows shows that the program has stopped working. In the build log it shows `Process terminated with status -1073741510`and sometimes `Process terminated with status 255`. Even though there's a return statement in the main function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void insert(int);
void print();
struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *link;
};
struct node *temp, *temp1, *temp2, *head, *end;
int main()
{
    int i, ch, a;

    head = NULL;
    temp = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    printf("Enter the number of items");
    scanf("%d", &ch);
    for(i = 0; i < ch; i++)
    {
        printf("\nEnter the number");
        scanf("%d", &a);
        insert(a);
        **call to insert**
        print();
    }
    return 0;
}

void insert(int x)
{
    temp = (node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    temp->data = x;
    temp->link = NULL;
    temp2 = head;
    if(head == NULL)
    {
        head = temp;
    }

    else
    {
        while(temp2 != NULL)
        {
            temp2 = temp2->link;
        }
        temp2->link = temp;
    }
}

void print()
{
    temp1 = head;
    printf("\nthe list is:");
    while(temp1 != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d", temp1->data);
        temp1 = temp1->link;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code is crashing due to a bug - if you run it in a debugger it'll tell you which line it crashes on and you'll hopefully be able to see the really obvious mistake you've made.

Comment: `temp2->link=temp;` : `temp2` is `NULL` after while-loop.

Comment: Too many global variables! The `temp1` in `print()` should be local to `print()`.  It would be better to pass the `head` to the function too.  The `temp` and `temp2` in `insert()` should be local variables too.  Here, you need care handling `head` — it would be better to pass it to the function and return the new head (the same as the old head except when adding the first element to the list).  You define `end` but never use it.  That's sloppy.

Answer (score -1):

This part of the function

```
else
{
    while(temp2 != NULL)
    {
        temp2 = temp2->link;
    }
    temp2->link = temp;
}
```

is wrong. After exit from the loop the node `temp2` is equal to NULL. Thus this statement

```
    temp2->link = temp;
```

results in undefined behavior.

Change the code snippet the following way

```
else
{
    while(temp2->link != NULL)
    {
        temp2 = temp2->link;
    }
    temp2->link = temp;
}
```

Also this statement in main

```
temp = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
```

does not make sense and leads to a memory leak.

These declarations of global variables except of the variable head

```
struct node *temp, *temp1, *temp2, *head, *end;
```

also do not make sense.